Receiving Continuous JSON Message Data Thru A C# Listener From A UDP Push Source
I am new to Socket programming in C#.  I am trying to set up a UDP Listener that will receive large amounts of JSON formatted data records from an indoor Locationing system.  Each record has over Key:Value fields. I am at the point where I can receive the first record, but I don't know how to write the code so that my listener receives the JSON Push records continuously.  The Source system could be sending 1000s of records every 15 to 20 secs. I will take any help I can get!  Thank you in advance.
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net.Sockets;


namespace QuuppaUDPListener
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            UdpClient QuuppaListener = new UdpClient(6900);
            IPEndPoint iPEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 6900);
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("waiting.....");
                byte[] receivedbytes = QuuppaListener.Receive(ref iPEndPoint);
                Console.WriteLine("Received a new Message Packet");
                string QuuppaPacket = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receivedbytes, 0,receivedbytes.Length);
                Console.WriteLine("qpe packet received:");
                Console.WriteLine(QuuppaPacket);


            }

            catch(Exception err)
            {

                Console.WriteLine(err.ToString());
            }
            Console.ReadLine(); //this is just to keep the console open so I could see the record once received
            QuuppaListener.Close();
        }
    }
}

Here is the first record of the array of JSON Records that the Source sends:
{"tagId":"000100000005","tagName":"Simulator001_0005","lastPacketTS":1712633404435,"color":"#FF0000","tagGroupName":"Asset Tags","locationType":"position","locationMovementStatus":"moving","locationRadius":0.63,"location":[95.28,68.56,1.20],"locationTS":1712633403129,"locationCoordSysId":"431fda80-3e31-48b6-8fa3-535f30744e74","locationCoordSysName":"CoordSys001","locationZoneIds":["b711d660-1e19-428d-a4f9-b169580a1a37"],"locationZoneNames":["Warehouse"],"button1State":"notPushed","button1StateTS":1712633404435,"button1LastPressTS":null,"batteryAlarm":"ok","batteryAlarmTS":1712633404435,"rssi":23,"rssiLocatorCount":16,"lastSeenTS":1712633404435}
I then want to store each of these records in a table as part of a  TagHistoryTbl

first, please add json example, and where are you planning to store data. also, check this link for example https://gist.github.com/darkguy2008/413a6fea3a5b4e67e5e0d96f750088a9

What is the actual question? Why do you want to use UDP? Do you have control over whatever is sending the requests? Both UDP and TCP require some kind of protocol on top to be usable, and UDP can be especially tricky unless you can absolutely guarantee that each message fits into a UDP package. I would at least consider some existing protocol, like http or MQTT or similar before trying to create something on my own.

Your example is already over the max safe udp limit for the internet. So you will may risk failures unless you can control the network.

Jonas, thank you for your feedback.  While I absolutely appreciate your comments, unfortunately, in business, you have to integrate to whatever the hardware/system provided gives you.  In this case, and according to the system provider, the data is sent via UPD Push which, btw, they say is the most effective and efficient way to send data from their system.  I am looking into MQTT and have used it for other similar Locationing systems.  I have also used Websockets for others.  However in this case I am limited to unacknowledged UDP Push messages. Any ideas on how to proceed?

Now, what might be helpful is that in nearly all cases the packet size will not change and the data is sent via INTRAnet connectivity, not Internet.
